# Remove all markup and inner text (except one) from a string using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string that has the following content -

```
<p> Are you eligible for sample?
<img src="/content/dam/aia-au-pd/rac-images/info_icon.gif">
<div class="tooltip_modal" style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">×</span>
      <h5>Tooltip</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some Text </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </p>
```

I want to extract `Are you eligible for sample?` and delete everything else.

I tried using `replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '')` but that gets rid of all HTML and preserves the all the text. Please note that I also want to get rid of "tooltip" and "some text" as shown in my code.

How do I achieve this using a regex pattern?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To clarify, you are asking specifically for a regex pattern?

Comment: @K_7 Yes! I have made the edits in my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this by using two regex replacements sequentially:

```
textString = inputString.replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '').replace(/\n(.*)/gm, '');
```

The first pattern, as you've noted already, removes the HTML tags. The second one matches everything but the first line, and removes it.

Test it using [Regexr](http://regexr.com/3gf78) (you can also try the "Replace" tool to see it in action -- click the button at the bottom, and change the replacement String to empty.